# C++ Why does this else if run after the if is true

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int userinp=-1,dig1=0,dig2=0,dig3=0,dig4=0;
    while(userinp!=0) {
        cin>>userinp;
        if (userinp=0) userinp=0;
        else if(userinp<0||userinp>9999) cout<<"Wrong input";
        else if (userinp<10) { dig1++; userinp =-1;}
        else if (userinp<100) {dig2++; userinp =-1;}
        else if (userinp<1000) {dig3++; userinp =-1;}
        else {dig4++; userinp =-1;}
    }
    cout<<dig1<<endl<<dig2<<endl<<dig3<<endl<<dig4;
    return 0;
    }
```

I'm trying an exercise from my school book but it gets stuck in an infinite loop because it runs the `else if userinp<10` when I type in 0. Why? If I delete the parts after the if goes out of the while.

Comment: increase warning level, and compiler should warn you about that mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have put an assignment (=) instead of equal check (==) inside your if condition part.

Change this line:

```
if (userinp=0) userinp=0;
```

to this

```
if (userinp==0) userinp=0;
```

And you should be good.

Good luck

Comment: doesn't an assignment statement in an if evaluate to true? Or is just garbage?

Comment: @Warpstar22 — the value of this assignment statement is 0.

Comment: @Warpstar22 If I am not wrong, each operation which is done in C++, it ends successfully, will return 0.  so not really garbage, a 0 is returned because the assignment has been done successfully. But it makes your if fails because 0 is counted as False. That is a very common mistake